# Unable to find my repository on jcenter in Android Studio

Tags: android, maven

I have successfully uploaded my repository on bintray and linked it to jCenter using this tutorial :- http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

I am sure that i have done everything the right way because i can access my repo on jcenter using this url :- http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/app/multiimagepickercropper/multipleImagePickerLib/1.0.2/

but when i am trying to access it in android studio by adding the line :-

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.app.multiimagepickercropper:multipleImagePickerLib:1.0.2'
}
```

I am sure my studio project is fine as i can add any other library and it is working but when i add mine, it throws an error :-

**Failed to find 'com.app.multiimagepickercropper:multipleImagePickerLib:1.0.2'**

This is my maven-metadata.xml on jcenter :-

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.app.multiimagepickercropper</groupId>
  <artifactId>multipleImagePickerLib</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.0.2</latest>
    <release>1.0.2</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20150610101307</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```